How to bypass the selenium script to make it initialize the InternetExplorer browser even when the screen goes to sleep in java
Selenium doesn't support the initialization of browser if I lock the screen soon after hitting the run button.
Throwing SessionNotCreatedException.
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
4.2.0.0
Listening on port 36346
Only local connections are allowed
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure. 
Host info: host: 'CPC-Shyam-XCKWB', ip: '10.94.128.70'
Build info: version: '4.8.2', revision: '826dbfc730'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_191'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ie.ensureCleanSession: true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: true}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, se:ieOptions: {ie.edgechromium: true, ie.edgepath: C:\Program Files (x86)\Micr..., ie.ensureCleanSession: true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: true, ignoreZoomSetting: true}}}]
Capabilities {}
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:561)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:119)
    at PIXEL.applb.initializeBrowser(applb.java:62)
    at PIXEL.AWD.main(AWD.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: NettyHttpHandler request execution error
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.execute(NettyHttpHandler.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:56)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.execute(NettyClient.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:36346 after 180000 ms
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.NettyResponseFuture.get(NettyResponseFuture.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyHttpHandler.makeCall(NettyHttpHandler.java:59)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Request timeout to localhost/127.0.0.1:36346 after 180000 ms
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.TimeoutTimerTask.expire(TimeoutTimerTask.java:43)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.timeout.RequestTimeoutTimerTask.run(RequestTimeoutTimerTask.java:50)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:715)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ImmediateExecutor.execute(ImmediateExecutor.java:34)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelTimeout.expire(HashedWheelTimer.java:703)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$HashedWheelBucket.expireTimeouts(HashedWheelTimer.java:790)
    at io.netty.util.HashedWheelTimer$Worker.run(HashedWheelTimer.java:503)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I tried making the script to bypass the validation of sleep mode by executing a command prompt script but didn't work.
And found that the below method in the RemoteWebDriver.class file causes the script to fail. Somewhere in the try block is failing which is why the toThrow variable in the catch block is making the script to fail.
protected Response execute(CommandPayload payload) {
    Command command = new Command(sessionId, payload);
    Response response;

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String currentName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    Thread.currentThread().setName(
      String.format("Forwarding %s on session %s to remote", command.getName(), sessionId));
    try {
      log(sessionId, command.getName(), command, When.BEFORE);
      response = executor.execute(command);
      log(sessionId, command.getName(), response, When.AFTER);

      if (response == null) {
        return null;
      }

      // Unwrap the response value by converting any JSON objects of the form
      // {"ELEMENT": id} to RemoteWebElements.
      Object value = getElementConverter().apply(response.getValue());
      response.setValue(value);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      log(sessionId, command.getName(), command, When.EXCEPTION);
      WebDriverException toThrow;
      if (command.getName().equals(DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION)) {
        if (e instanceof SessionNotCreatedException) {
          toThrow = (WebDriverException) e;
        } else {
          toThrow = new SessionNotCreatedException(
            "Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.", e);
        }
      } else if (e instanceof WebDriverException) {
        toThrow = (WebDriverException) e;
      } else {
        toThrow = new UnreachableBrowserException(
          "Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.", e);
      }
      populateWebDriverException(toThrow);
      toThrow.addInfo("Command", command.toString());
      throw toThrow;
    } finally {
      Thread.currentThread().setName(currentName);
    }

    try {
      errorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(response, System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
      populateWebDriverException(ex);
      ex.addInfo("Command", command.toString());
      throw ex;
    }
    return response;
  }

I'm expecting the script to run without expecting the screen to be awake.
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
    // selenium script
}, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date())+"2024-06-12 09:40:00"));

So that while using this above method It can run the script without being screen dependent.
